# Change WCF client host address - dynamic binding security

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

I frequently want to change the host URL for a WCF service client during testing. In my config, I usually have a binding like this:

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ListsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="5120000" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

It's easy enough to swap out the address at runtime:

```
ServiceClient svc = new ServiceClient();
svc.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://wherever");
```

The problem is if I'm changing the address from https to http, calling the service will blow up saying it expects https because it's trying to use transport security.

It seems the Binding of svc.Endpoint is read-only and can only be set in the constructor. I can create a binding with the correct security mode, but then I lose all of the other property values that are configured in the config file. I don't want to have to try to explicitly copy them. Is there a way to create a new BasicHttpBinding using the configuration file's `<binding>` and to then change it's security mode so I can instantiate svc with using binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a service handy to test this with, but you might be able to do the following:

1. Create a new `BasicHttpBinding`, passing in the configuration name
   from your config file.
2. Set the `Security.Mode` to `None`.
3. Pass the new binding in to the service client overloaded constructor that takes a binding and an endpoint address.

Something like this:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("ListsSoap");
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

ServiceClient svc = new ServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://wherever"));
svc.Open();
```

In short, do all the binding configuration stuff before you create the client, since as you've already noticed once the client channel is created there's not much you can change.

Comment: I'm very confused. I tried your code and it does work, but if the Mode property is writable here, it should be writable on the ServiceClient instance too. And it is. I can set either the binding's Mode, or replace the entire Binding itself after svc is instantiated. I could swear yesterday it would not let me set them and the descriptions said "Sets..." not "Gets or sets ...". At any rate, I didn't know you could create the BasicHttpBinding passing the configuration name, which was the key to the approach I originally _thought_ was necessary. I would vote down my own question if I could...

Answer (score 1):

So here's an example of how I would do it:

```
public partial class ListsSoapClient
{
    protected override ListsSoap CreateChannel()
    {
#if DEBUG
        //When debugging, change the binding's security mode
        //to match the endpoint address' scheme.
        if (this.Endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme == "https")
            ((BasicHttpBinding)this.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        else
            ((BasicHttpBinding)this.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
#endif

        return base.CreateChannel();
    }  
}
```

So my code to call the service can remain untouched:

```
ServiceClient svc = new ServiceClient();
svc.Call();
```

This way I can simply change the service URL in the web or app.config without having to change the binding, maintain multiple bindings, or mess with my calling source code. This gives us one less thing to have to remember to change back after completing debugging, which is especially convenient if you have undisciplined developers on your team or developers who don't understand binding configurations. CreateChannel is also a convenient place to set credentials at runtime.